# How to set PageOptions in TuesPechkin

Tags: c#, .net, wkhtmltopdf, tuespechkin

I'm using [TuesPechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin) (the C# wrapper of wkhtmltopdf) and have it generating PDF files from HTML.

However, I would like to set the `--disable-smart-shrinking` option, which is listed in the [wkhtmltopdf documentation](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) as a PageOption

How can I do that?

```
public sealed class PdfConverter
{
    static readonly PdfConverter instance = new PdfConverter();
    private IConverter converter;

    static PdfConverter()
    {
    }

    PdfConverter()
    {
        // Keep the converter somewhere static, or as a singleton instance! Do NOT run this code more than once in the application lifecycle!
        this.converter = new ThreadSafeConverter( new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>( new Win32EmbeddedDeployment( new TempFolderDeployment())));
    }

    public static PdfConverter Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public byte[] ConvertHtmlToPdf(string html)
    {
        var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
        {
            Objects = { new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = html } }

            // Where are PageOptions?  Thats where --disable-smart-shrinking is
        };

        return converter.Convert(document);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--disable-smart-shrinking` option does not exist in the API -- well, it *kind of* does, but in the form of it's opposite sibling: `--enable-smart-shrinking`.

That property is available in the TuesPechkin API as `WebSettings.EnableIntelligentShrinking` [as seen in the TuesPechkin source code](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/blob/develop/TuesPechkin/Document/WebSettings.cs#L20). It was named that way in TuesPechkin because that is how it is named in wkhtmltopdf's API [as seen in the wkhtmltopdf source code](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/7f74d893635d275f9450bf5f12c454a9c27672bd/src/lib/websettings.cc).

You can also see there that the default value is true (from wkhtmltopdf), so if you set `WebSettings.EnableIntelligentShrinking` to `false` you should get the result you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this functionality hasn't been implemented in Tuespechkin. I can't find it [here](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/blob/develop/TuesPechkin/Document/LoadSettings.cs), where most of the page options are located.

I guess he forgot to implement the option, so probably best to request the feature [here](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin/issues). Or you can also add the feature yourself. :)